# Not correct orientation of the OBB Box

Tags: c++, orientation, quaternions, point-cloud-library, bounding-box

Im using PCL library to obtain the orientation of detected objects. Basically i only need to get the OBB of the object (Box on the ground). So for that I was using the Moment of Inertia from this tutorial [PCL Tutorial](https://pcl-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment_of_inertia.html?highlight=moment%20of%20inertia). So first, I filter the cloud using the Pass through Filter, then done the planar segmentation to remove the ground floor. And at the end I used the extracted point cloud Box( without the plane surface) to get the OBB of the box object.
At the end I visualize it the OBB in Rviz (ROS).
Here the code in C++ (PCL and ROS).

```
ros::Publisher pub, markers_pub_;

void cloud_cb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr &msg){

    // Convert to pcl point cloud
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_msg (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    pcl::fromROSMsg(*msg,*cloud_msg);
    //ROS_DEBUG("%s: new ponitcloud (%i,%i)(%zu)",_name.c_str(),cloud_msg->width,cloud_msg->height,cloud_msg->size());

    // Filter cloud
    pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZRGB> pass;
    pass.setInputCloud(cloud_msg);
    pass.setFilterFieldName ("y");
    pass.setFilterLimits(0.001,10);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    pass.filter (*cloud);

    // Get segmentation ready
    pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients(new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
    pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers(new pcl::PointIndices);
    pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZRGB> seg;
    pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZRGB> extract;
    seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
    seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
    seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
    seg.setDistanceThreshold(0.04);

    // Create pointcloud to publish inliers
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_pub(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    

        // Fit a plane
        seg.setInputCloud(cloud);
        seg.segment(*inliers, *coefficients);

        // Check result
        if (inliers->indices.size() == 0)
           {
            ROS_WARN_STREAM ("Could not estimate a planar model for the given dataset.") ;
            }


        // Extract inliers
        extract.setInputCloud(cloud);
        extract.setIndices(inliers);
        extract.setNegative(true);
        //pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloudF;
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_box (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ());
        extract.filter(*cloud_box);
       
  //Moment of Inertia
  pcl::MomentOfInertiaEstimation <pcl::PointXYZRGB> feature_extractor;
  feature_extractor.setInputCloud (cloud_box);
  feature_extractor.compute ();

  std::vector <float> moment_of_inertia;
  std::vector <float> eccentricity;

  pcl::PointXYZRGB min_point_OBB;
  pcl::PointXYZRGB max_point_OBB;
  pcl::PointXYZRGB position_OBB;
  Eigen::Matrix3f rotational_matrix_OBB;
  float major_value, middle_value, minor_value;
  Eigen::Vector3f major_vector, middle_vector, minor_vector;
  Eigen::Vector3f mass_center;

  feature_extractor.getMomentOfInertia (moment_of_inertia);
  feature_extractor.getEccentricity (eccentricity);
  feature_extractor.getOBB (min_point_OBB, max_point_OBB, position_OBB, rotational_matrix_OBB);
  feature_extractor.getEigenValues (major_value, middle_value, minor_value);
  feature_extractor.getEigenVectors (major_vector, middle_vector, minor_vector);
  feature_extractor.getMassCenter (mass_center);

  Eigen::Vector3f position (position_OBB.x, position_OBB.y, position_OBB.z);
  Eigen::Quaternionf quat (rotational_matrix_OBB);
   
  cout << " orientation x  = " << quat.x() <<  endl;
  cout << " orientation y = "  << quat.y() <<  endl;
  cout << " orientation z = "  << quat.z() <<  endl;
  cout << " orientation w = "  << quat.w() <<  endl;
  cout << " postion x  = " << position_OBB.x <<  endl;
  cout << " postion y  = " << position_OBB.y <<  endl;
  cout << " postion z  = " << position_OBB.z <<  endl;
   

    // Publish points
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud_publish;
    pcl::toROSMsg(*cloud_box,cloud_publish);
    pub.publish(cloud_publish);

  //Visualisation Marker
  std::string ns; 
  float r; 
  float g; 
  float b;
  visualization_msgs::MarkerArray msg_marker;
  visualization_msgs::Marker bbx_marker;
  bbx_marker.header.frame_id = "zed_left_camera_frame";
  bbx_marker.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  bbx_marker.ns = ns;
  bbx_marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::CUBE;
  bbx_marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
  bbx_marker.pose.position.x =  position_OBB.x;
  bbx_marker.pose.position.y =  position_OBB.y;
  bbx_marker.pose.position.z =  position_OBB.z;
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.x = quat.x();
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.y = quat.x();
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.z = quat.x();
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.w = quat.x();
  bbx_marker.scale.x = (max_point_OBB.x - min_point_OBB.x);
  bbx_marker.scale.y = (max_point_OBB.y - min_point_OBB.y);
  bbx_marker.scale.z = (max_point_OBB.z - min_point_OBB.z);
  bbx_marker.color.b = b;
  bbx_marker.color.g = g;
  bbx_marker.color.r = r;
  bbx_marker.color.a = 0.4;
  bbx_marker.lifetime = ros::Duration();
  msg_marker.markers.push_back(bbx_marker);
  markers_pub_.publish(msg_marker);

}

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Initialize ROS
  ros::init (argc, argv, "my_pcl_tutorial");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  // Create a ROS subscriber for the input point cloud
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("/zed/zed_node/point_cloud/cloud_registered", 200, cloud_cb);
  // Create a ROS publisher for the output point cloud
  pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("cloud_publish", 100);
  markers_pub_ = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::MarkerArray> ("msg_marker", 100);
    ros::spin();
  ros::spin ();
}
```

Here the point cloud scene.

[image: The whole pointcloud scene]

Then the extracted box and the visualized OBB.

[image: Visualized OBB]

So my question is why the orientation of the OBB is not correct? is not aligned with the red box. Also the output is following

```
orientation x  = 0.553429
 orientation y = 0.409076
 orientation z = 0.575402
 orientation w = 0.441912
 postion x  = 0.688811
 postion y  = 0.296049
 postion z  = -0.0444195
 orientation x  = 0.551899
 orientation y = 0.41675
 orientation z = 0.556839
 orientation w = 0.460061
 postion x  = 0.6858
 postion y  = 0.297214
 postion z  = -0.0479018
 orientation x  = -0.447575
 orientation y = 0.523119
 orientation z = -0.488997
 orientation w = 0.535635
 postion x  = 0.687003
 postion y  = 0.296398
 postion z  = -0.0541157
 orientation x  = -0.435059
 orientation y = 0.533038
 orientation z = -0.483508
 orientation w = 0.541123
 postion x  = 0.689015
 postion y  = 0.299274
 postion z  = -0.0532807
 orientation x  = -0.483639
 orientation y = 0.486945
 orientation z = -0.526589
 orientation w = 0.50168
 postion x  = 0.687567
 postion y  = 0.290984
 postion z  = -0.0566443
 orientation x  = -0.451907
 orientation y = 0.514618
 orientation z = -0.499482
 orientation w = 0.530533
 postion x  = 0.688489
 postion y  = 0.300407
 postion z  = -0.0544657
 orientation x  = -0.462979
 orientation y = 0.508457
 orientation z = -0.503387
 orientation w = 0.523185
 postion x  = 0.687322
 postion y  = 0.294014
 postion z  = -0.0556483
 orientation x  = 0.507688
 orientation y = 0.462501
 orientation z = 0.530055
 orientation w = 0.497381
 postion x  = 0.687552
 postion y  = 0.293263
 postion z  = -0.055368
 orientation x  = -0.413774
 orientation y = 0.554115
 orientation z = -0.456901
 orientation w = 0.559455
```

As can see orientation change as well. Please, any help how to improve the results?
Thanks

Comment: This looks suspicious: `bbx_marker.pose.orientation.x = quat.x();
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.y = quat.x();
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.z = quat.x();
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.w = quat.x();`. Always `quat.x()` on RHS? (Really?) ;-)

Comment: ups sorry was a typo. Of course should be   bbx_marker.pose.orientation.x = quat.x(); bbx_marker.pose.orientation.y = quat.y(); bbx_marker.pose.orientation.z = quat.z(); bbx_marker.pose.orientation.w = quat.w(); Was just a typo. What is RHS?

Comment: RHS ... right hand side. Was it a typo in your application or just in the exposed code? In the former case, it might be the reason why the orientation is not like expected...

Comment: why let say for example  orientation w change from 0.45 to 0.58. Why such a  range?The cout was correct orientation but in the visualization marker in the application was typo as well.  Ok will correct and check results again. thanks

Comment: Are you a little bit familiar with [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)? You have a real part and 3 imaginary parts. Normalized quaternions are a common tool to describe rotations - spherical interpolation can be achieved quite easy with them. Beside of this, they are difficult to imagine (at least, for me) and I personally prefer 4x4 matrices or Euler angles if I have the choice. TL;DR: I simply cannot tell you whether the _w change from 0.45 to 0.58_ indicates anything... ;-)

Comment: If you are uncertain I would use something to turn the quaternions into a 3x3 matrix or a 4x4 matrix or Euler angles for debug output. The APIs you are using surely provide something for this. (Even if not - algorithms can be easily found by a google search.)

Comment: so means bbx_marker.pose.orientation.x = quat.x(); bbx_marker.pose.orientation.y = quat.y(); bbx_marker.pose.orientation.z = quat.y(); bbx_marker.pose.orientation.w = quat.w() is not the correct way to obtain the orientation? So better way is with 4x4 Rotation MAtrix or Euler angles? How to obtain then them?

Comment: so the way is turn the  quaternions into a 3x3 matrix or a 4x4 matrix or Euler angles. Then from 3x3 matrix or a 4x4 matrix or Euler angles how to obtain the orientation?

Comment: There is a typo again: `bbx_marker.pose.orientation.z = quat.y();`. I mean if you have something (a library) which provides a quaternion and something else (the same or another library) that consumes quaternion then there is nothing wrong with quaternions. If you want to justice "by eyes" whether the values make sense then it is easier with a matrix or Euler angles. You could convert the values for print-debugging aside from passing them as is to their destination.

Comment: In a 3x3 rotation matrix the columns are just the rotated unit axes. So, they have to be all normalized and they have to be upright to each other. After practicing it a bit (e.g. with your [right hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule)), you might be able to "see" the rotation in the pure values. (Once, one of my professors looked over my shoulder on my screen and said "Ah, a rotation matrix." which left me deep impressed. Meanwhile, it makes me smiling as it's really not that difficult if you are familiar with matrices.)

Comment: I would like to have something to justice "by eyes" whether the values make sense. So for that purpose need to convert quaternion into 4x4 Rotation Matrix or Euler angles. Right? then from there?

Comment: but I would like to visualize like the bbx_marker.pose.orientation. So can justify it by eyes and can visualize the marker with correct orientation

Comment: _Right? then from there?_ Wasn't your original intention to find out why your OBB doesn't have the orientation it should? (OBB ... Oriented Bounding Box I guess.) So, a typo in assigning the orientation (given as quaternion) is a very possible source for this. So, I would start with fixing the code. If this doesn't help then you should verify whether the received values make sense. That's of course easier if they are provided in an understandable way... (and, for me, quaternions don't belong to this).

Comment: yes . I fixed the code. Now is bit better. bit still is not exactly oriented as the object(the red box). So how to improve the code? so the OBB is exactly oriented as the object in the scene (red box) and get exactly orientation of the object (red box)?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when there's an issue with rotations in 3D, the frames of reference used by different libraries is often different and need correction before being passes between them (in this case ROS and PCL). I can't say if that's the problem here.

However, I also see the following issue in the code presented:

```cpp
  // notice all assignments are from x() to {x,y,z,w}
  // they should be from x() to x, y() to y and so on and so forth
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.x = quat.x();
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.y = quat.x();
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.z = quat.x();
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.w = quat.x();
```

It appears that either

1. you're not assigning the orientation correctly **OR**
2. you've not synced the code and images with your observations

Comment: sorry that was a typo. That solve the issue. Now the OBB is correct. Only need to convert the Quaternions is something more readable for the eyes like 4x4 matrices or Euler angles

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It was a typo in

```
bbx_marker.pose.orientation.x = quat.x();
bbx_marker.pose.orientation.y = quat.x();
bbx_marker.pose.orientation.z = quat.x();
bbx_marker.pose.orientation.w = quat.x();
```

I should be

```
bbx_marker.pose.orientation.x = quat.x();
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.y = quat.y();
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.z = quat.z();
  bbx_marker.pose.orientation.w = quat.w();
```